# Odd behaviour with phalcon php logger

Tags: php, logging, phalcon

I am trying to use the logger (https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/3.2/logging) in a micro application like this:

```
<?php

// Load required namespaces
use Phalcon\DI\FactoryDefault;

// Initialize the application
include getcwd() . '/../app/bootstrap.php';

// Create a new di to share resources across the application
$di = new FactoryDefault();

// Register singleton instance of the loaded config object
$di->setShared('config', function() use ($config) {
    return $config;
});
$config = null;

// Register singleton instance of the logger adapter
$di->setShared('logger', function() {
    return Phalcon\Logger\Factory::load([
        'name' => APP_DIR . 'storage/logs/' . date('d-m-Y') . '_logs.txt',
        'adapter' => 'file'
    ]);
});

// Create our micro Phalcon application
$app = new Phalcon\Mvc\Micro();
$app->setDI($di);

// Base api end point page
$app->get('/', function() use ($di) {
    include(APP_DIR . 'home.php');
});

// Post-process request request
$app->after(function() use ($di, $start)
{
    // Log request
    if ($di->get('config')->app->debug) {
        $di->get('logger')->debug(sprintf("Processed request for %s in %f seconds.\r\n",
            $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
            ( microtime(true) - $start)));
    }
});

// Global 404 error handler
$app->notFound(function() {
    throw new Exception('File not found.');
});

// Register global exception handler
set_exception_handler(function($exception) use ($di)
{
    // Log unhandled exception as an error
    $logger = $di->get('logger');
    $logger->begin();
    $logger->error($exception->getMessage());
    $logger->debug($exception->getFile() . ':' . $exception->getLine());
    $logger->debug("StackTrace:\r\n" . $exception->getTraceAsString() . "\r\n");
    $logger->commit();
});

// Start handling api requests
$app->handle();
```

When I visit the application base end point page (i.e. `http://app.local/`), I am seeing my "home" page content.

In the log, I see two entries:

```
[Sat, 22 Jul 17 04:56:12 +0100][DEBUG] Processed request for 127.0.0.1 in 0.000000 seconds.

[Sat, 22 Jul 17 04:56:13 +0100][ERROR] File not found.
[Sat, 22 Jul 17 04:56:13 +0100][DEBUG] C:\xampp\htdocs\app.local\public\index.php:98
[Sat, 22 Jul 17 04:56:13 +0100][DEBUG] StackTrace:
#0 [internal function]: {closure}()
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\app.local\public\index.php(114): Phalcon\Mvc\Micro->handle()
#2 {main}
```

What's triggering the 404 not found?

---

I am using Apache 2 + PHP 5.6 on my local dev env. Here are the contents of my `.htaccess` files:

**C:\xampp\htdocs\app.local\.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ public/ [L]
RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
```

**C:\xampp\htdocs\app.local\public\.htaccess**

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?_url=/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Apache's vhost `DocumentRoot` is set to `C:\xampp\htdocs\app.local`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out the problem. It's nothing to do with the code or the `.htaccess` rewrites.

When the api call is made in the browser (e.g. Chrome), it appears the browser is also making a request to the `favicon.ico` file as shown here:

[image]

I am working on an API Application and there is no real front end (except the help page on the home route), so there was no such file and hence the log.

Easy fix is to create a blank `favicon.ico` in the `public` dir solves the problem.

Comment: Then i would recommend to add also information about url you access in your logger so next time it will save you time.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I have now done this for every requests.

Answer (score 0):

It's triggered when url is not found as the name of the method tells, i guess it's about your nginx/apache config most likely.

Comment: I am using the standard rewrite in my `.htaccess` like this: `AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?_url=/$1 [QSA,L]` in the "public" dir where in "index.php" is

Comment: and the document_root of my app (where the apache vhost points to) has the following `RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ public/ [L]
RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]` in the `.htaccess` file

Comment: And what url you access? You sure it's `/` ? As i remember micro is not removing slashes and for some reason it's hard coded, so there is difference between `$app->get('/')` and `$app->get('')`

Comment: I've figured it out, see my answer.